# RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (710) : device-side assert triggered at /pytorch/aten/src/THCUNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.cu:110

Tags: python

**Hello!I'm reproducing SSN, but when I was training, this problem occurred. I only used the first four categories in the thumos14 dataset. Please help me!**

The num_class=4

The main:

```
def main():   
    global args, best_loss    
    args = parser.parse_args()  
    dataset_configs = get_configs(args.dataset)   

    num_class = dataset_configs['num_class']     
    stpp_configs = tuple(dataset_configs['stpp'])
    sampling_configs = dataset_configs['sampling']
       
    model = SSN(num_class, args.num_aug_segments, 
                args.num_body_segments, args.num_aug_segments,
                args.modality,
                base_model=args.arch, dropout=args.dropout,
                stpp_cfg=stpp_configs, bn_mode=args.bn_mode)
                           ...
    train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader( 
        SSNDataSet("", train_prop_file,
                   epoch_multiplier=args.training_epoch_multiplier,
                   new_length=data_length,
                   modality=args.modality, exclude_empty=True, **sampling_configs,
                   aug_seg=args.num_aug_segments, body_seg=args.num_body_segments,
                   image_tmpl="img_{:05d}.jpg" if args.modality in ["RGB", "RGBDiff"] else args.flow_prefix+"{}_{:05d}.jpg",
                   transform=torchvision.transforms.Compose([
                       train_augmentation,
                       Stack(roll=(args.arch in ['BNInception', 'InceptionV3'])),
                       ToTorchFormatTensor(div=(args.arch not in ['BNInception', 'InceptionV3'])),
                       normalize,
                   ])),
        batch_size=args.batch_size, shuffle=True,
        num_workers=args.workers, pin_memory=pin_memory,
        drop_last=True)
```

the ssn

```
 def __init__(self, num_class,          
                 starting_segment, course_segment, ending_segment, 
                 modality,base_model='resnet101', new_length=None,           
                 dropout=0.8,
                 crop_num=1, no_regression=False, test_mode=False,
                 stpp_cfg=(1, (1, 2), 1), bn_mode='frozen'):
                 super(SSN, self).__init__()
     self._prepare_base_model(base_model)   

     feature_dim = self._prepare_ssn(num_class, stpp_cfg)
```

and the train:

```
 activity_out, activity_target, \
        completeness_out, completeness_target, \
        regression_out, regression_labels, regression_target = model(input_var, scaling_var, target_var,
                                                                     reg_target_var, prop_type_var)
```

the loss

```
    act_loss = act_criterion(activity_out, activity_target)
    comp_loss = comp_criterion(completeness_out, completeness_target,ohem_num, comp_group_size)
    reg_loss = regression_criterion(regression_out, regression_labels, regression_target)
    loss = act_loss + comp_loss * args.comp_loss_weight + reg_loss * args.reg_loss_weight
    reg_losses.update(reg_loss.item(), out_frames.size(0))
```

I just run

```
(SSN) win@win-Blade-15-Base-Model-Early-2020-RZ09-0328:~/PycharmProjects/SSN$ CUDA_LAUNCH_BLOCKING=1 python ssn_train.py thumos14 RGB -b 2 --lr_steps 20 40 --epochs 45
```

The output

```
Freezing all BatchNorm2D layers
computing regression target normalizing constants

            
            SSNDataset: Proposal file data/thumos14_tag_val_proposal_list.txt parsed.
            
            There are 3292 usable proposals from 22 videos.
            703 foreground proposals
            2285 incomplete_proposals
            304 background_proposals
            
            Sampling config:
            FG/BG/INC: 1/1/6
            Video Centric: True
            
            Epoch size multiplier: 10
            
            Regression Stats:
            Location: mean -0.01399 std 0.08622
            Duration: mean -0.02407 std 0.19567
```

But the error:

```
/pytorch/aten/src/THCUNN/ClassNLLCriterion.cu:106: void cunn_ClassNLLCriterion_updateOutput_kernel(Dtype *, Dtype *, Dtype *, long *, Dtype *, int, int, int, int, long) [with Dtype = float, Acctype = float]: block: [0,0,0], thread: [0,0,0] Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/pytorch/aten/src/THCUNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.cu line=110 error=710 : device-side assert triggered
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ssn_train.py", line 442, in <module>
    main()
  File "ssn_train.py", line 162, in main
    train(train_loader, model, activity_criterion, completeness_criterion, regression_criterion, optimizer, epoch)
  File "ssn_train.py", line 226, in train
    act_loss = act_criterion(activity_out, activity_target)
  File "/home/win/anaconda3/envs/SSN/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 532, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/home/win/anaconda3/envs/SSN/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/loss.py", line 916, in forward
    ignore_index=self.ignore_index, reduction=self.reduction)
  File "/home/win/anaconda3/envs/SSN/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 2021, in cross_entropy
    return nll_loss(log_softmax(input, 1), target, weight, None, ignore_index, None, reduction)
  File "/home/win/anaconda3/envs/SSN/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 1838, in nll_loss
    ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (710) : device-side assert triggered at /pytorch/aten/src/THCUNN/generic/ClassNLLCriterion.cu:110
```

and I just print the

```
activity_out: tensor([[-0.0008,  0.0856,  0.0711,  0.0326, -0.0167],
        [ 0.0041,  0.0238,  0.0365,  0.0042, -0.0623],
        [ 0.0445,  0.0882,  0.0490,  0.1352, -0.0677],
        [ 0.0469, -0.0210,  0.1010,  0.0610, -0.0176]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<IndexBackward>)
activity_target: tensor([2, 0, 1, 0], device='cuda:0')
Epoch: [0][0/110], lr: 0.00100  Time 4.966 (4.966)      Data 0.587 (0.587)      Loss 1.6920 (1.6920)    Act. Loss 1.588 ( 1.588)        Comp. Loss 1.025 ( 1.025)       Reg. Loss 0.016 (0.016)
 Act. FG 0.00 (0.00) Act. BG 0.00 (0.00)
activity_out: tensor([[ 0.0014,  0.4088,  0.0502, -0.1568, -0.2318],
        [ 0.1841,  0.0647,  0.0729, -0.1160, -0.1725],
        [ 0.1171,  0.0263,  0.0699, -0.2004, -0.1274],
        [ 0.1754,  0.0582,  0.0352, -0.0821, -0.1320]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<IndexBackward>)
activity_target: tensor([3, 0, 3, 0], device='cuda:0')
activity_out: tensor([[ 0.3940,  0.0500, -0.0160,  0.0139, -0.4481],
        [ 0.3940, -0.0226, -0.0322, -0.0716, -0.2665],
        [ 0.6110,  0.0894, -0.1844, -0.0678, -0.4758],
        [ 0.6179,  0.2419, -0.2166, -0.1169, -0.4899]], device='cuda:0',
       grad_fn=<IndexBackward>)
activity_target: tensor([8, 0, 1, 0], device='cuda:0')
```

I don't know how to deal with it.PLease help me!Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The issue is likely related to `Assertion `t >= 0 && t < n_classes` failed.`. When you reduced the number of classes, did you correctly ensure that class labels only lie in {0,1,2,3}?

Comment: maybe like this?I think you are right. I just use the BaseballPitch、BasketballDunk、Billiards and CleanAndJerk，I think it in {0,1,2,3}. How can I print the label?Thanke you!

Comment: You do seem to be printing the labels, `activity_target`. And in the last output, you have an 8, which is out of range of {0,1,2,3}. Try finding out how you got an 8 there.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try it!  This should be because a video contains multiple action categories .

Comment: Yes, but since you are filtering it to four, you should have only four possible targets. And to work correctly they must be mapped to 0-3. And looking at your other outputs you already have targets covering 0,1,2,3, so it seems you have at least five distinct targets. So there may be some mistake in how you filter.